# Calendar notifications on Apple Watch

Tags: iphone, calendar, notifications, apple-watch

I'm facing issues with iOS Calendar notifications on Apple Watch.

I use Fantastical as my phone / watch calendar. I disabled the iOS Calendar notifications on my iPhone, and set the iOS Calendar watch notifications to mirror iPhone alerts.

Then, I deleted the iOS Calendar app.

The issue, is that I get two notifications every time, one from Fantastical (which is fine), and one from iOS Calendar app (which is wrong).

How can I prevent the iOS/watchOS Calendar app to notify me ever again?

- iPhone 7 (iOS 10.3.1)
- Apple Watch series 2 (watchOS 3.2)

Comment: Have you tried force rebooting both the Apple Watch and your iPhone? (holding the digital crown and the side button on the Watch; holding the power button and the Home button/Touch ID on your iPhone (except for the iPhone 7 and newer)

Comment: Yep, several times.

Comment: How did you "delete the calendar app" and on which device?

Comment: On iphone. Same way as you delete other apps.

Comment: This just hides the stock Calendar.app within iOS. Please update your questions with your devices and the iOS/watchOS versions on your them. This may be helpful. I had a similar behavior with notification from another app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with Bridge.app (Apple Watch app on iOS) not syncing properly.

To force iOS sync all notification settings properly to your Apple Watch follow these steps.

*As this takes some time, please try force reboot each device separately first. Check if the bug still persists.*

---

### Fix notification issues with an Apple Watch (watchOS 3.2)

1. iOS App Store: "Re-install" the iOS Calendar app
2. iOS: In Bridge.app (Apple Watch app on iOS) **enable** iOS Calendar notifications for Apple Watch
3. iOS Settings: **enable** iOS Calendar notifications
4. iOS: Force **reboot your iPhone**. Wait for it to connect to your Apple Watch.
5. watchOS: Force **reboot your Apple Watch**. Wait for the Watch to connec to your iPhone.
6. iOS: In Bridge.app (Apple Watch app on iOS) **disable** iOS Calendar notifications for Apple Watch (without mirroring)
7. iOS Settings: **disable** iOS Calendar notifications
8. iOS: In Bridge.app, **unpair** your Apple Watch
9. iOS: Pair your Apple Watch and **restore** it from your last backup.

Note: After you restore your Apple Watch backup, you may need to re-pair it to your Mac in order to unlock it with the Watch.

Comment: Points 8 and 9 are no needed. If I delete calendar.app after point 7 actually works.